# How to find non-inherited properties of a type via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to retrieve properties from a class that are declared in a specific type, excluding the ones inherited from base types.

Of course it's a trivial example, but I wanted to extract the simplest code possible.

The real case scenario's a bit more complex, so I don't really want to change the approach.

Here is my code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyVehicles vehicles = new MyVehicles();

        Type objectToInspectType = vehicles.GetType();

        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = objectToInspectType.GetProperties(); 

        foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertyInfos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.PropertyType.Name); // Return Vehicle, Vehicle instead of Car, Car
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {
        WheelCount = 4;
    }

    public int WheelCount { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car()
    {
        Color = 10;
    }

    public int Color { get; set; }
}

public class MyVehicles
{
    public MyVehicles()
    {
        vehicle1 = new Car();
        vehicle2 = new Car();
    }

    public Vehicle vehicle1 { get; set; }
    public Vehicle vehicle2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want two properties (Car & Car and not Vehicle & Vehicle).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get the declared properties try using the `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`

Here is a snippet that gets all the `Public`, `Instance` and `DeclaredOnly` properties.

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = objectToInspectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Binding Flags Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx

Based on your example class here is the result for each type.

`typeof(Car)`: 1 Property `Color`

`typeof(Vehicle)`: 1 Property `WheelCount`

`tyepof(MyVehicles)`:  2 Properties `vehicle1`, `vehicle2`

**Updated**

Based on the comments what you are actually looking for is the `Type` of the value assigned to the property. As the property is a `Vehicle` the method above will return `typeof(Vehicle)`. Now it is expected that the property will be a type of `Vehicle`. However as you are down-casting the `Car` to a `Vehicle` you need to check the value of the property.

This can be done following another answer given by MarcinJuraszek, I have put the two solutions together for an example.

*Note if the value is `null` then the property type will be `Vehicle` as that is its declared type. If the value is given then we can check the `Type` of the value.*

Here is a full solution that gets only the `Declared` properties [I.E. not inherited from a base class].

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyVehicles vehicles = new MyVehicles();
    Type objectToInspectType = vehicles.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = objectToInspectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertyInfos)
    {
        Type propertyType = item.PropertyType;
        object value = item.GetValue(vehicles, null);
        if (value != null)
            propertyType = value.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine(propertyType.Name); 
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When you run that the output will be `Car`, `Car` as the values of the properties `vehicle1` and `vehicle2` are set to a value of the type `Car`. The magic happens in the lines:

```
Type propertyType = item.PropertyType;
object value = item.GetValue(vehicles, null);
if (value != null)
    propertyType = value.GetType();
```

Where we declare the variable `propertyType` to the type of the property `item.PropertyType`, next we get the value from the `vehicles` for that property with the line `object value = item.GetValue(vehicles, null);`. If the value is set (ie not `null`), then we set the variable `propertyType` to the type of value using `value.GetType()`.

If you were to unset the value of `vehicle1` (set it `null`) the property type returned by the method above will be `Vehicle`.

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I wan't is to display Car & Car instead of Vehicle & Vehicle which is the case with :     PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = objectToInspectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer based on your comments.. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To get actual type of object which is assigned to that property and not declared property type use following:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertyInfos)
{
    var value = item.GetValue(vehicles);
    var type = value == null ? item.PropertyType : value.GetType();
    Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helps me. Just modifying a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

the corrected version

```
foreach (PropertyInfo item in propertyInfos)
        {
            Object value;

            if (item.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
            {
                value = item.GetValue(vehicles, null);
            }
            else
            {
                value = item.GetValue(vehicles, new object[] { 0 });  // string property is returned as a char array and consequently need index
            }

            Type  type = value == null ? item.PropertyType : value.GetType();
            Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
        }
```